# How to print query output received inside javascript in html table format inside ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

Inside abc.ejs, I have script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var socket = io.connect();

     socket.on('date', function(data){
     //      alert(JSON.stringify(data));

     });
</script>
```

How do I print the database query output received in `data` in HTML table format?

Comment: first try to use console.log (console.log(data)) and open the debugger (F12 on chrome) see what is the result you see in data, maybe you need to use data.data instead of just data

Comment: yes, I tried that, it prints the value as expected. But I need to print the same in HTML table.

Comment: please add to the question what you get and what should be the output